# Add Name Value Pairs into an Array and Print - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm relatively new to Javascript, therefore im struggling on this.

Basically, Im trying to output the ID and Value of an array in Javascript but im not sure if im printing it out wrong or the values are not being added to the array.

**The Javascript**

```
$('body').on('click','.checkbox',function(){
    $('.checkbox').on('change', function () {
        var total = 0;
        $('.check:checked').val(function (idx, val) {
            total += +val;
            return val;
        });
        $('#result').text(total);


        var vals = [this.value];
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input:checkbox[name="checkboxes[this.value]"]').each(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                vals.push(this.value);
            }
        });         
            alert(vals.toString());
        });

    }); 
});
```

**The Checkbox**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="<?php echo $count*0.50 ?>" Name ="checkboxes[<?php echo $closePC ?>]">
```

Comment: What are you want and what is your result?

Comment: I also have a product total javascript function running that updates the total on the screen. The alert is just for testing purposes

Comment: @OP, One can not execute this provided code as we do not have `php` environment created for your code. It is always better to provided parsed html for better understanding of the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    var arrCheckboxData = [];
    function saveCheckboxDataToArray()
    {
        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            var strCheckboxName = $(this).attr("name");
            arrCheckboxData[strCheckboxName] = $(this).val();
        });
        console.log(arrCheckboxData);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        saveCheckboxDataToArray();
        $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
            saveCheckboxDataToArray();
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I can see this working in console. How do I print this specific array? Also, how you you assign the name value (not the checkbox value) to an html text input?

Comment: I still need to find out how to print to HTML, I can see it printing in console

Comment: Please provide your desirable output that you need to print in HTML

Comment: Just the name value, without the array name

i.e. foo, foo1 instead of arrCheckboxData['foo'], arrCheckboxData['foo']

Comment: <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="A" />
So in this case do you need 1 or A ?